# scrollIntoView() Not working on input change or blur

Tags: angular, js-scrollintoview

I have an input field that either on `(blur)` or on `(change)` triggers a function that should scroll the page to the next element block. For reasons I ignore it doesn't work, although it works fine when used on `(click)` with buttons. I am also sure that the function gets called properly. It simply looks like `scrollIntoView` gets ignored.
Do you guys know what could be the reason?

`<input type="number" (change)="scrollToNext(i)"">`

```
private scrollToNext(i) {
   this.arrayOfElements[i + 1].scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start'})
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found that onChange events seem to block certain transitions, I'm not sure why.

But a work-around is to call some callback such as `setTimeout`:

```
private scrollToNext(i) {
    let arr = this.arrayOfElements;

    setTimout(() => {
        arr[i + 1].scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start'});
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: Had the same issue, when an `onChange` event was fired from an `<input>` element by defocusing the element. Interestingly, `scrollIntoView` worked fine if the `onChange` event was fired by pressing the `Enter` key. Struggling to find any documentation of this feature, would be great if anyone could point me in the right direction to better understand this issue

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check if browser support this function
https://caniuse.com/#feat=scrollintoview

Secondly The element may not be scrolled completely to the top or bottom depending on the layout of other elements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is not the case. As I mentioned the `scrollIntoView` works fine when triggered by buttons in the same scenario. It doesn't look like a matter of Browser or layout.